# Loading resource bundle for all locales at application startup in Spring boot

Tags: spring

I'm writing a REST API using Spring RestTemplate and I'm fetching messages from resource bundle using `ResourceBundleMessageSource` like this:

```
bundle.setBasename("messages");
bundle.getMessage(key, null, locale);
```

The problem is, the API will be called from multiple locations, and I need to fetch the locale specific messages. But I do not want to load the locale specific properties file every time the API is called (Isn't this very inefficient?). I want to load the properties file only once when the application starts.

Basically, it should work as if the property files for all the locale have been loaded in memory, and we just fetch the information from the memory.  How do I avoid fetching the locale specific resource file every time and yet get locale specific messages?

Thanks.

Comment: ResourceBundle has a cache. It's optimized already. You shouldn't try to optimize some code until you have a performance problem and you have proven that code is the culprit.

Comment: You shouldn't be creating those things, just add a `ResourceBundleMessageSource` to your config. Inject a `MessageSource` and use that to retrieve the messages. The bundles will be loaded once.